# Implementing 'equal Vect' with DecEq

Tags: equality, idris

I tried to implement the following:

```
headEqual : DecEq a => (x : a) -> (y : a) -> Maybe (Dec (x = y))
headEqual x y = case decEq x y of
                  Yes Refl  => Just (Yes Refl)
                  No contra => Nothing

vectEqual : DecEq a => (xs : Vect n a) -> (ys : Vect n a) -> Maybe (Dec (xs = ys))
vectEqual []         []         = Just (Yes Refl)
vectEqual (x :: xxs) (y :: yys) = case headEqual x y of
                                  Just (Yes prf) => vectEqual xxs yys
                                  No contra      => Nothing
vectEqual (x :: xxs) []         = Nothing
vectEqual []         (y :: yys) = Nothing
```

However, it fails to compile:

```
*section3> :r
Type checking ./section3.idr
section3.idr:45:63-66:
When checking right hand side of Main.case block in vectEqual at section3.idr:44:40 with expected type
        Maybe (Dec (x :: xxs = y :: yys))

When checking argument xs to Main.vectEqual:
        Unifying len and S len would lead to infinite value
Holes: Main.y, Main.vectEqual
```

I don't understand this compile-time error. Can someone please explain?

Comment: You should remove the last two clauses for `vectEqual` since they cannot occur since both vectors have the same length.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the non-empty case you need two proofs - one that the heads are equal and one for the tail. You then need to combine these proofs into one for the input vectors. In:

```
Just (Yes prf) => vectEqual xxs yys
```

you are trying to return a proof for the tail when you need a proof for the entire list. You need to check the result of the recursive call to build the proof e.g.

```
vectEqual : DecEq a => (xs : Vect n a) -> (ys : Vect n a) -> Maybe (Dec (xs = ys))
vectEqual [] [] = Just (Yes Refl)
vectEqual (x :: xs) (y :: ys) = case decEq x y of
  Yes hd_prf => case vectEqual xs ys of
    Just (Yes tl_prf) => ?combine_proofs
    _ => Nothing
  No contra => Nothing
```

If you load the above definition in the repl you will see the types of `hd_prf` and `tl_prf`:

```
hd_prf : x = y
tl_prf : xs = ys
```

you can use `rewrite` to construct the required proof of `(x :: xs) = (y :: ys)`

```
Just (Yes tl_prf) => rewrite hd_prf in rewrite tl_prf in Just (Yes Refl)
```

Note the return type of this function is a bit strange since you are using `Nothing` to encode the failure case which `Dec` already provides using the `No` constructor, so you never return `Just (No _)`.